# Load NVIDIA module for X and load nouveau module for framebuffer: automatically

Tags: kernel-modules, nvidia, framebuffer, nouveau

NVIDIA driver doesn't have support for framebuffer console.

I want Linux kernel to automatically load NVIDIA for X window system, and nouveau for framebuffer console.

There should be a method to implement automatic load/unload process, right? How can I implement that in LFS 7.9.